# My framework is not connecting to Browserstack

Tags: browserstack

I signed up an account in browserstack. Edited My xml file and enabled it to true. It keeps saying that it does not recognize my browser version or the OS.Here is my code in XML file.

```
<parameter name="useCloudEnv" value="true"/>
<parameter name="cloudEnvName" value="browserstack"/>
<!--<parameter name="cloudEnvName" value="saucelabs"/>-->
<parameter name="os" value="Windows"/>
<parameter name="os_version" value="10"/>
<parameter name="browserName" value="chrome"/>
<parameter name="browserVersion" value="60.0"/>
<parameter name="url" value="https://www.uhc.com//"/>

<test name = "Test">
    <classes>
         <class name="testhomepage.TestHomePage"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Comment: I commented out my saucelab

Answer (score 0):

Please find below link, I ran a sample test on BrowserStack Automate with the same capabilities you are providing in the XML file:

https://automate.browserstack.com/builds/5854b3a5d9e5e91d1562b5daeb33460e64e11599/sessions/e0102645e1af034a26cd7c7abb52257b4c506185?auth_token=6607bebe9a9de8fbd062fe46324a4c64aecabc5242d835b48bd8876a0727ee22

Please refer BrowserStack sample code here:
https://www.browserstack.com/docs?product=automate

To find the BrowserStack capabilities click here:
https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities

You have mentioned the correct BrowserStack capabilities in the XML file but make sure your tests scripts are receiving the same capabilities.

Could you please review your framework once?